# JSONDecode json format error from terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-sql-database, jq, terraform-provider-azure

Trying to add sql dbs created from azure portal to azure failover group.

Terraform block will call bash script :

```
data "external" "database_names" {
  program = ["sh", "${path.module}/scripts/fetch_db_id.sh"]
  query = {
    db_rg            = azurerm_resource_group.mssql.name
    server_name      = azurerm_mssql_server.mssqlserver.name
  }
}
```

fetch_db_id.sh bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This script will get the database names at runtime.
eval "$(jq -r '@sh "export DB_RG=\(.db_rg) SERVER_NAME=\(.server_name)"')"

if [[ -z $DB_RG || -z $SERVER_NAME ]]; then
echo "Required variables DB_RG & SERVER_NAME not set" 1>&2
exit 1
fi

db_id=$(az sql db list --resource-group $DB_RG --server $SERVER_NAME --query [*].id | grep -v master 2>/dev/null)

jq -n --arg db_id "$db_id" '{"db_id":$db_id}'

unset DB_RG SERVER_NAME NODE_RG db_id

exit 0
```

Bash script output : Ran it locally on a linux VM without terraform :

*"db_id": "[\n "/subscriptions/my_subscription_id/resourceGroups/sql_rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sql_server_name/databases/databaseprd-db1",\n "/subscriptions/my_subscription_id/resourceGroups/sql_rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sql_server_name/databases/databaseprd-db2",\n "/subscriptions/my_subscription_id/resourceGroups/sql_rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sql_server_name/databases/databaseprd-db3"\n]"
}*

Terraform resource block to add database inside failover group:

```
resource "azurerm_sql_failover_group" "mssql_failover" {
  count                         = (var.enable_read_replica  && var.environment == "prd") ? 0 : 1
  name                          = var.mssql_failover_group
  resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.mssql.name
  server_name                   = azurerm_mssql_server.mssqlserver.name
  databases                     = toset(jsondecode(data.external.database_names.result["db_id"]))
  partner_servers {
    id = azurerm_mssql_server.replica[0].id
  }

  read_write_endpoint_failover_policy {
    mode                        = "Automatic"
    grace_minutes               = 60
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_mssql_server.replica
  ]
}
```

terraform error code: when executed via terraform jenkins pipeline

*[1mdata.external.database_names.result["db_id"][0m is "[\n  "/subscriptions/my_subscription_id/resourceGroups/sql_rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sql_server_name/databases/databaseprd-db1",\n  "/subscriptions/my_subscription_id/resourceGroups/sql_rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sql_server_name/databases/databaseprd-db2",\n  "/subscriptions/my_subscription_id/resourceGroups/sql_rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sql_server_name/databases/databaseprd-**db3",\n]"**
Call to function "jsondecode" failed: invalid character ']' looking for
beginning of value*

Note: it is introducing an extra "," when we run it with terraform jenkins pipeline, which could lead to json error.

Comment: The use of eval looks suspicious.

Comment: You call out the extra comma, but you also have partial ANSI escape codes in there, the `[1m` and `[0m`. Are they really present or an artefact introduced by however you acquired the log? Similarly, is the italic and bold formatting on purpose or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's enough information here to be certain, but I can give a partial, speculative answer.

```
az sql db list --resource-group $DB_RG --server $SERVER_NAME --query [*].id | grep -v master 2>/dev/null
```

This looks suspicious: the `az` command outputs JSON, but you're filtering it with grep. What does the output from `az` look like here? Do you expect the result to be valid JSON?

You say that our output has a comma that you don't expect. This is what you'd expect to see if the `az` command spat out something like:

```
[
  "/blah/blah/databaseprd-db1",
  "/blah/blah/databaseprd-db2",
  "/blah/blah/databaseprd-db3",
  "/blah/blah/master"
]
```

The `grep -v master` would remove the line containing the term "master", leaving you with invalid JSON:

```
[
  "/blah/blah/databaseprd-db1",
  "/blah/blah/databaseprd-db2",
  "/blah/blah/databaseprd-db3",
]
```

If you want to use `jq`, you could replace the grep with something like

```
jq 'map(select(index("master")|not))'
```

Comment: issue was with grep -v leading to extra ","
using `az sql db list --resource-group $DB_RG  --server $SERVER_NAME--qu
ery [*].id | jq 'map(select(index("master")| not))'  2>/dev/null` resolved it.

Comment: Oops, I will fix the answer there to include the `not`, I got mixed up. Glad to hear it got you on the right track.